# How can I resolve the error with RGtk2 and run Rattle via Docker on Mac?

Tags: r, docker, macos, rattle, rgtk2

I have been trying to get Rattle installed on my Mac, but got lots of different issues during days of attempt.

I have then discovered the possibility to do it via Docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/kayon/rattle) - which magically worked on an Apple Silicon Mac.

However, this did not work again when I tried to follow the same steps on another Mac (Intel chips - not sure if this is a reason). The error occured at the last step as shown on kayon/rattle to actually start rattle:

```
> ...
> library(rattle)
> rattle()
# Error in rattle() : Can't load RGtk2.
# A windowing system can't be accessed?
# Maybe you are using a remote terminal (ssh) or RStudio browser connection.
# Consider using remote desktop, ssh -X, or X2Go depending on your platform.
# Running rattle() locally on a desktop is the default.
# >
```

Any one had the same issue or had an idea what is it about?

Install different versions of R, RStudio (locally) and use different methods to install XQuartz; Unstall and clear data from R and all of the above applications (on top of previous attempts to install XQuartz in different ways, install rattle of differnt versions and using different commands (locally)